# Cakephp 3 json result query on datetime

Tags: php, json, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here is my derp moment, stuck... I have an ajax call going to a controller action and I have a query comparing two datestamps and I get the below error:

front end js loop and ajax

```
    while(count <= toursToday){
                    tourtimeFormatted = moment.utc(tourtime);
                    var html = '<button data-id="<?= $tour->id ?>" data-timeslot="'+tourtimeFormatted+'" class="btn btn-default timeSlot">'+formatAMPM(tourtime)+'</button>';
                    $('#tourDetails').append(html);
                        tourtime.setMinutes(tourtime.getMinutes() + 30);                        
                    console.log(tourtime);

                    count++;
                }

    $('body').on('click', 'button.timeSlot', function() {
                alert('clicked');
                var time = $(this).data('timeslot');
                var tour_id = $(this).data('id');
                //ajax get avaliable seats
                $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "/getseats.json",
                  data: { tour_id: tour_id, date_time: time }
                })
                  .success(function( data ) {


                  });
            });
```

Error and Backend showing more about what is happening. I think I have the dates comparison wrong, but I'm not sure where...

```
    2016-06-15 14:56:29 Error: [BadMethodCallException] Unknown finder method  "Array"
    Request URL: /getseats.json
    Referer URL: http://paddletap.lan/book-a-tour/6
    Stack Trace:
    #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PaddleTapRedesign/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php(943): Cake\ORM\Table->callFinder(Array, Object(Cake\ORM\Query), Array)
    #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PaddleTapRedesign/src/Controller/TourController.php(98): Cake\ORM\Table->find(Array)
    #2 [internal function]: App\Controller\TourController->getseats()
    #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PaddleTapRedesign/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(429): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PaddleTapRedesign/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(114): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
    #5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PaddleTapRedesign/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\TourController))
    #6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PaddleTapRedesign/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
    #7 {main}


    2016-06-15 15:08:23 Warning: Warning (2): strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in [/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PaddleTapRedesign/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/BehaviorRegistry.php, line 215]
    Trace:
    Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 147
    strtolower - [internal], line ??
    Cake\ORM\BehaviorRegistry::hasFinder() - CORE/src/ORM/BehaviorRegistry.php, line 215
    Cake\ORM\Table::callFinder() - CORE/src/ORM/Table.php, line 1787
    Cake\ORM\Table::find() - CORE/src/ORM/Table.php, line 943
    App\Controller\TourController::getseats() - APP/Controller/TourController.php, line 98
    Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 429
    Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 114
    Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 87
    [main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37


    public function getseats()
    {
    $orders = TableRegistry::get('Orders');

    $tour_id = $_POST['tour_id'];
    $date_time = $_POST['date_time'];
    $new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_time));


    //find order items for tour id
    $bookings = $orders->find([
        'conditions' => [
            DATE('Orders.booking_date_time') => $date_time
        ]
    ])->all()
    ;

    //where date is M-d-yy
    //where time is H:i
    $this->set('bookings', $bookings);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['bookings']);

    }
```

Comment: does the error say which line is causing the conversion error? but that exact error occurs when you have something like `$foo = array(); echo $foo;` or `$bar = 'this will end well' . $foo` - using an array in a string context.

Comment: I think it's the query, what is being passed in is 2016-07-17T15:00:00-05:00

Comment: Here are the error messages attached to the response:

Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE/src/ORM/Table.php, line 1782]
Warning (2): strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE/src/ORM/BehaviorRegistry.php, line 215]
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE/src/ORM/Table.php, line 1792]

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post the _complete_ error message including the _full_ stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion) in your question, even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (x.x.x)!

Comment: I know, but that's not the _exact_ version, the exact version number consits of three numbers, like `3.2.1` (check `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`). Without knowing the exact version, it's extremely hard to figure to what code an error message refers to. Ideally you'd also put _that_ in your question.

Comment: Sorry, it's cake3.2.3

Comment: since those errors are inside cake itself, it's probably caused by something you're doing, e.g. `some_cake_function($array)` where it should be `some_cake_function($string)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Table::find()` expects a string for the first argument, the find type. You are passing an array, hence the error.

**http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_find**

Such errors should be rather easy to figure by closely inspecting the error message, and checking the corresponding code. Ideally, look at the stacktrace and check the code flow.

Besides that, your conditions are wrong, you are calling the PHP `date()` function there, which in the end would cause an error too, as you'd pass a date string as the column, which of course doesn't exist. Your condition should be like

```
'Orders.booking_date_time' => $date_time
```

Also it should not be necessary to manually format the time, you should be able to simply create a `\DateTime` or `\Cake\I18n\Time` instance from it, like

```
'Orders.booking_date_time' => new \DateTime($date_time)
```

where `$date_time` is the raw input.

And another, kind of unrelated thing, do not access superglobals like `$_POST` directly! This will just cause problems, at the very least in the test environment. Use the request object to retrieve input, like `$this->request->data('date_time')`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Request Body Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data)**

Comment: Thanks for helping, that sucked. and thanks for the constructive info about not access $post directly.! cheers